# Adding external Link using ckeditor to ionic mobile applicaion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a php admin to create content for a mobile application using ionic framework, everything works perfectly.
but I have a little problem.
when the admin create a content and put an external link, this link is not working, even it looks like a link in the mobile application.

This is what I get from the php when requesting the page

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "created_date": "2015-05-19 09:09:39",
  "title": "Grade 12 Graduation Ceremony",
  "description": "<p><a href=\"http:\/\/ais.arrowad.sch.sa\/index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&amp;view=article&amp;id=249:ais-igcse,-as,-a2-and-american-diploma-overview%E2%80%8F&amp;catid=41&amp;Itemid=538&amp;lang=en\">AIS IGCSE, AS, A2 and American Diploma Overview&rlm;<\/a></P
",
  "image": "1432012362.jpg",
  "thumbail": "",
  "lang": "all",
  "date": "2015-05-19",
  "timestamp": "1432044579"
}
```

I am prining the html like this :
in the controller

```
 angular.module('App')
        .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
            return function(text) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            };
        }]);
```

and in the html

```
<div ng-bind-html="data.content| to_trusted"></div>
```

so the link is not clickable, even I tried to make the link as a javascript "OnClick" but its the same problem

any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look how your link is rendered:

```
  "description": "<p><a href=\"http:\/\/ais.arrowad.sch.sa\/index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&amp;view=article&amp;id=249:ais-igcse,-as,-a2-and-american-diploma-overview%E2%80%8F&amp;catid=41&amp;Itemid=538&amp;lang=en\">AIS IGCSE, AS, A2 and American Diploma Overview&rlm;<\/a></P
```

The closing tags are broken:

```
<\/a></P
```

A normal html link should look like for example:

```html
 <a href="www.example.com">This is my link</a>
```

Comment: So what should do ? Its working if I I print it in the browser

Comment: How do you show the content? In a browser or in a custom mobile application?